Yocto Build gnutls: Libhogweed (nettle's companion library) 3.6 was not found
I have been trying to build the gnutls in my yocto build. I have been using the gnutls_3.7.4. I keep getting the following error that Libhogweed is missing.
The error I have copy pasted below:-

| checking dependency style of aarch64-poky-linux-g++  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/user/kirkstone-yocto/linux_build/src/imx-yocto-bsp/build_imx8dxccu/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/gnutls/3.7.4-r0/recipe-sysroot... none
| checking for bison... no
| checking for byacc... no
| checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) sed
| checking whether to build with code coverage support... no
| checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
| checking for inline... inline
| checking for egrep... (cached) /home/user/kirkstone-yocto/linux_build/src/imx-yocto-bsp/build_imx8dxccu/tmp/hosttools/grep -E
| checking for __get_cpuid_count... no
| checking for struct iovec.iov_base... yes
| checking for netinet/tcp.h... yes
| checking for stdatomic.h... yes
| checking for library containing __atomic_load_4... -latomic
| checking for threads.h... (cached) yes
| checking for sanitizer/asan_interface.h... no
| checking for valgrind/memcheck.h... no
| checking for getrandom... yes
| checking for KERN_ARND... no
| checking for getentropy... no
| checking for nettle >= 3.6... yes
| checking for hogweed >= 3.6 ... no
| configure: error:
|   ***
|   *** Libhogweed (nettle's companion library) 3.6 was not found. Note that you must compile nettle with gmp support.
| 
| NOTE: The following config.log files may provide further information.
| NOTE: /home/user/kirkstone-yocto/linux_build/src/imx-yocto-bsp/build_imx8dxccu/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/gnutls/3.7.4-r0/build/config.log
| ERROR: configure failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/user/kirkstone-yocto/linux_build/src/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-support/gnutls/gnutls_3.7.4.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'


I have tried to install libhogweed6, nettle-dev, nettle-bin. Nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me out please ?
